# how to fix elements after resize it on angular

Tags: angular

I'm using 'ResizableModule' on angular9 and my div now resizable but when I release the div it initiated and return to its size.

I used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-element that Package.

then how to fix its size after release.

my component.ts:

```
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit
{
        public style: object = {};

    onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
        console.log('Element was resized', event);
        this.style = {
            position: 'fixed',
            left: `${event.rectangle.left}px`,
            top: `${event.rectangle.top}px`,
            width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
            height: `${event.rectangle.height}px`
          };
    }
```

Html:

```
<div
      mwlResizable
      [enableGhostResize]="true"
      [resizeEdges]="{ bottom: true, right: true, top: true, left: true }"
      (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)"
         style="width: 95%;" 
      > </div>
```

component.scss:

```
mwlResizable {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

there is a simple example on stackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rowwg

Answer (score 0):

After debugging your stackblitz solution i have noticed that created style css at the end of resizeEnd function is not applying to resizable div.

Here i have added style using ngstyle so whenever this.style variable changes new ngstyle will adjust css according to variable

Here is your solution

*app.component.js*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ResizeEvent } from 'angular-resizable-element';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public style: object = {};
       onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
        console.log('Element was resized', event);
        this.leftPosition = event.rectangle.left;
        this.topPosition = event.rectangle.top;
        this.divWidth = event.rectangle.width;
        this.divHeight = event.rectangle.height;
        this.style = {
            position: 'fixed',
            left: `${this.leftPosition}px`,
            top: `${this.topPosition}px`,
            width: `${this.divWidth}px`,
            height: `${this.divHeight}px`
          };
          console.log(this.style)
    }
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<div
      mwlResizable
      [enableGhostResize]="true"
      [resizeEdges]="{ bottom: true, right: true, top: true, left: true }"
      (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)"
      style="border:1px solid red;" [ngStyle]="style"> i'm resizales</div>
```

Here is stackblitz url for my solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efhdra

Comment: Upload your solution to stackbitz

Comment: A shame that it does not resize element alone